# See a function signature in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to see just the function signature in Node.js?  I'm aware of `fn.toString()` but don't want all the code, just the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var source = fn.toString();
var signature = source.substring(0, source.indexOf('{') - 1);
```

is probably the closest you’ll get; fall back on `fn.length` for native methods.

Comment: Definitely works, was hoping for something built-in rather than deriving the signature from something else.  Will accept in 10 minutes (when SO lets me).  Thanks